# Clearing text in canvas doesn't let me redraw

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, web

I'm working on a game in canvas (possibly easier ways to do this but I wanted to learn HTML5, etc.). Anyways, I have a points counter I'm working on and one of two things happen.

1. If I don't clear the canvas before writing the value they all (obviously) overlap into nothing readable
2. However, if I clear the context first and then write I end up with nothing.

   ```
   PointsScored.prototype.writePointsToCanvas = function(){
       var canvas = document.getElementById("pointsScoredCanvas")
       var context = canvas.getContext("2d")
       context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);

       context.fillStyle("black")
       context.font="30px Verdana"
       context.fillText("Score " + this.points, window.innerWidth * 0.8, window.innerHeight * 0.1)

   }
   ```

If you need anymore information lemme know. I have everything spread out into files and objects (it kills me to throw everything under one script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is referencing a none-existing element which will break the code before the `fillText` call.

This line:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
```

should be:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Also, `fillStyle` is a property and should read like this:

```
context.fillStyle = "black";  // use as property, not method
```

Hope this helps!